# NSString does not have a member named bridgeToObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am getting a compiler error in the code below. I have imported the required Foundation library so I am not sure exactly what is wrong, please could someone suggest what I might be doing incorrectly or what I might do in order to fix this?

Thanks

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var areaTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var resultLbl: UILabel!

    @IBAction func goBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

        if(countElements(areaTxt.text) > 0){
            var removedSpaces = areaTxt.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "");
            var url = "http://weather-forecast.com/locations/" + removedSpaces + "/forecasts/latest";
            self.getWeatherReportForArea(url);
        }else{
            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Alert"
            alert.message = "The user location is empty"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            alert.show()
        }
    }

    func getWeatherReportForArea(area: String){
        var url = NSURL(string: area);
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);

            if(urlContent.bridgeToObjectiveC().containsString("<span class=\"phrase\">")){

                var contentArray = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("<span class=\"phrase\">");
                var newContentArray = contentArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</span>");

                var value = newContentArray[0].stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&deg;", withString: "º");

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                    self.resultLbl.text = value;
                }

            }else{

            }
        }

        task.resume();
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bridgeToObjectiveC()` was removed in Xcode 6 Beta 5. Now bridging is transparent, simply use

```
if urlContent.containsString("<span class=\"phrase\">") {
    ...
}
```